# Не учитываются фильтры при заполнении поля

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Не фильтруются товары учитывая другие переменные, кроме переменной поиска. Поиск происходит при помощи данной функции:

```
$('#menu-search').bind('keyup', function(){
        $('#pagination').twbsPagination('destroy');
        $('#pagination').html('<div class="empty_goods">Загрузка содержимого..</div>');
        var $this = $(this);
        var $delay = 500;

        clearTimeout($this.data('timer'));

        $this.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
        $this.removeData('timer');
        begin = 0;
        
            total_p_ajax();
        
        }, $delay));

});
```

А фильтрация по каким-либо критериям с помощью этого:

```
$('.common_selector').click(function(){
total_p_ajax();
    });
```

Но при поиске, не учитываются критерии которые "checked" в данных блоках:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами критерии передаются с помощью этого:

```
function filter_data()
    {
        begin = begin;
        var referal = $('#menu-search').val();
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var genres = get_filter('genres');
        $.ajax({
            url:"assets/function/catalog/fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, genres:genres, referal:referal, begin:begin},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

function total_p_ajax(){
page_number = 1;
begin = 0;
total_page = total_pages();
if (total_page > 0) {
if (total_page < 24) {
total_page = 1;
}
else{
total_page = Math.ceil(total_page/24);
}

$('#pagination').twbsPagination('destroy');
$('#pagination').twbsPagination({
        startPage: page_number,
        totalPages: total_page,
        visiblePages: 5,
        prev: '<span aria-hidden="true">Назад</span>',
        next: '<span aria-hidden="true">Вперед</span>',
        first: '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>',
        last: '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>',
          onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            page_number = page;
            if (page_number == 1) {
            begin = 0;
            }
            else{
            begin = (page_number-1)*24; 
            }

            filter_data();
            
          }
});
}
```

Все работает хорошо, но когда начинаешь заполнять поле поиска, то выводятся только те товары, которые соответствуют названию, но не учитываются критерии "checked".
Код get_filter():

```
function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте html разметку, чтоб понимать что и откуда вытекает, + что отправляется в запросе? Туда же передаются данные из фильтров

Comment: Фильтр по жанрам у вас формируется функцией get_filter. Покажите код get_filter.